# many to many with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

well, the problem is this. I have this tables.

item , person , person_item

then i do the relationship Many to Many in the model and in the controller of person i use person.items.build and use the fields_for in the view i have ALL but in the relationship table person_item is like this

```
create_table "person_items", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "person_id"
t.integer  "item_id"
t.integer  "num"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

i don't know how add the field cant when the fields person_id and item_id of relationship is fill
how i do the view for this?

part of view of person

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :nom %><br />
<%= f.text_field :nom %>
</div>
----Items-----
<% f.fields_for :items do |builder|%>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :nomItem %><br />
<%= f.text_field :nomItem %>
</div>
```

i think is some like this but this fills 2 rows, one with num and all blank and the other without num.

```
<% f.fields_for :person_items do |pi|%>
<div class="field">
<%= pi.label :num %><br />
<%= pi.text_field :num %>
</div>
<%end%> #end of person_items
<%end%> #end of items
```

Comment: Are you using has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through? You should be using has_many :through.

Comment: i using has_many  :through because, the cant is from the relationship example:  john has a cant(number) of items

Comment: is cant like a cart that a person adds items to?

Comment: i edit it, the attribute is number like, John has 8 items.